# WebView - нет подключение к blockchain (ETHEREUM)

Tags: android, webview

Имеются некоторые DApps на эфире (Ethereum), их мы интегрируем в мобильное приложение (просто передаем туда url и открываем через WebView).
В чём проблема: если на клиенте, где мы открываем DApp, нет подключения к эфиру, то фронтенд мы всё равно видим и можем с ним как-то взаимодействовать, но бэкенд для нас недосупен, и приложение не работает.
Как проблема решается: через браузер на компе подключиться к эфиру можно при помощи плагина MetaMask для Google Chrome, но нужно как-то ещё подключаться и на телефоне, чтобы в установленной .APK можно было работать с DApp через мобильное приложение. Возможно, это можно сделать при помощи установки на телефон какого-то стороннего ПО, возможно что-то нужно сделать на сервере. Кто у нас тут самый умный, подскажите?

Comment: нужно реализовать функционал MetaMask  на телефоне

Comment: @ArcherGodson Логично, а где конкретно его реализовать и как?